# How to allow only two front slash in a input box

Tags: javascript, regex, html

```
pattern="\d{4}"
```

As the above is used to allow only only 4 digits I want to allow only two '/' for a input field accepting fractions 1/2,4/6 the next fraction should not be allowed ! What is the regrex code for that I am new to regrex and not able to understand it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex `([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\,([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)`
It will match only 1/2,4/6 type of strings.

Comment: How to implement this in javascript ! var re =([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\+([0-9]+\/[0-9]+);
var str="1/2,3/4";
str.match(re);
error is shown

Comment: var str = "3/4,5/6";var patt = /([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)\,([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)/;var result = patt.test(str);console.log(result);